# How to add a fourth, unrelated to all others, circle to matplotlib-venn.venn3 diagram

Tags: matplotlib-venn

I'm using the awesome [matplotlib_venn](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn) to plot Venn diagram derived from three binary conditions. Unfortunately, besides the 7 cases covered by the `venn3` function, my case includes an all false (`'000'`) group.

Is there any built in way to do so?

I've failed to find it myself, so any instructions to hijack this plot (or correlated hacks) to include it by myself in the output is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib-venn` is build on top of matplotlib so you can add a circle with the normal matplotlib commands.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
venn3(subsets, ax=ax)
c = plt.Circle((x, y), radius) 
ax.add_patch(c)
```